# How do I change content based on query string?

Tags: php, switch-statement, echo

I want to add some extra functionality to a WordPress (PHP) theme file.

I'm using a ref id, and adding this to the URL (as a query string). I would like the HTML to change depending on the string. Basic description:

```
if
/?ref=email1
echo 'This HTML'

or if 
/?ref=email2
echo 'This other HTML'

or if neither
echo 'Default HTML'
```

The code I've come up with so far is below (however not working):

```
switch($_GET){
    case !empty($_GET['email1']):
        HTML here
    break;

    case !empty($_GET['email2']):
        This other HTML
    break;

    default:
        Default HTML
    break;
}
```

How can I fix my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it wrong way. `$_GET` is a `array`. You can't implement `swicth` this way. May be it would be like -

```
switch($_GET['ref']){
    case 'email1':
       HTML here
    break;

    case 'email2':
         This other HTML
    break;   

    default:
         Default HTML
    break;

}
```

You can try this trick -

```
$contents = array(
  'email1' => 'HTML here',
  'email2' => 'This other HTML'
);

if(!empty($contents[$_GET['ref']])) {
    echo $contents[$_GET['ref']];
} else {
    Default HTML
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the contents of `email1` and `email2`, parameters that don't exist in `$_GET`. You need to use `ref` instead.

```
switch($_GET['ref']){
  case "email1":
    echo "HTML here";
    break;
  case "email2":
    echo "Other HTML here";
    break;
  default:
    echo "Default HTML here";
    break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this spudmonkee! This helpef me solve the problem :) only thing I had to do was remove the : after case and it worked perfectly..

switch($_GET['ref']){
  case "email1":
    echo "HTML here";
    break;
  case "email2":
    echo "Other HTML here";
    break;
  default:
    echo "Default HTML here";
    break;
}